# watchman : don't pipe matched files in trigger

Tags: makefile, watchman

I'm working on a Makefile and gave a try at [watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/). Here is the content of the Makefile for the moment :

```
compile:
    elm-make app/Main.elm

watch:
    watchman watch `pwd`/app
    watchman trigger -- `pwd` compile 'app/*.elm' -- make compile
```

The problem here is that when a watched file is changed, let's say Other.elm, the executed command is `make compile Other.elm`.

`make compile` is correct but `make Other.elm` doesn't correspond to anything in the Makefile, so I have an error in the watchman log file.

How could I don't take in account the matched file in the command triggered ? Could it be done only with the CLI options, and not using `watchman -j` ?

Comment: Do you want watchman to execute the command `make compile`? Or do you want Make to ignore "Other.elm"?

Comment: I want it to execute the command exactly `make compile`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that the docs aren't super clear.  What you need to do is use the extended trigger syntax to register your trigger.  You have to use the `-j` option to be able to pass in the JSON representation of the command:

```
watchman -j <<-EOT
["trigger", "`pwd`", {
   "name": "compile",
   "expression": ["match", "elm/*.elm", "wholename"],
   "command": ["make", "compile"],
   "append_files": false
}]
EOT
```

https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cmd/trigger.html#extended-syntax
has more info on the extended syntax.  The important portion of this is the `append_files` bit.

You'll need to find a way to express that multi-line command in your Makefile; my instinct is just to use the `\` line continuation character at the end of each line, but I haven't double checked the docs.

Also note that you can use this alternative syntax to put the invocation on a single line if your shell is bash or zsh.  I've typed this in by hand and may well have messed up the quoting(!):

```
watchman -j <<< "[\"trigger\", \"`pwd`\", {\"name\": \"compile\", \"expression\":[\"match\", \"elm/*.elm\", \"wholename\"], \"command\": [\"make\", \"compile\"], \"append_files\": false}]"
```

https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cli-options.html#input-and-output
has a little more background on invocation.

Comment: Watchman 4.1 ships with a new tool called [watchman-make](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/watchman-make.html) that should make this type of usage pattern a bit easier